# Project 2010: Failed and blocking correlation

Tags: project-server

We are using Project 2010 with SP2 (KB2687452) for timesheet management. We have a single staff always get stuck in queue when he submit timesheet weekly. When it happened, we cancel the queue job and then he can submit again and work.

The error details:

> **General**
>
> Timesheet: TimesheetIncorrectMode (3204). Details: id='3204'
> name='TimesheetIncorrectMode'
> uid='ba3507c4-6951-475a-ab57-29cd79328c7a' mode='1'.  Queue:
> GeneralQueueJobFailed (26000) -
> TimesheetSubmit.SubmitTimesheetMessage. Details: id='26000'
> name='GeneralQueueJobFailed'
> uid='a3234295-d2e6-490d-9f9c-b25f2d144b93'
> JobUID='59d4ef1b-cac8-4cc5-90ac-794696e6f038' ComputerName='HKEPMAP01'
> GroupType='TimesheetSubmit' MessageType='SubmitTimesheetMessage'
> MessageId='1' Stage=''. For more details, check the ULS logs on
> machine HKEPMAP01 for entries with JobUID
> 45d4ef1b-cac8-4bb5-12ac-994696e6f038.

We have 200 staffs submit timesheet weekly and only he get this problem. What could I check?

Comment: What's the current CU of your farm

Comment: It is SP2 (KB2687452)